# Typed container in Scala collections

Tags: scala

Essentially, I require a *heterogeneous map* but I'm aware that this is not easy to implement.

```
trait Box[T] {
    def exec(): T
}
class IntBox extends Box[Int] {
    def exec() = 69
}
class StringBox extends Box[String] {
    def exec() = "foo"
}
```

So, when I put `Box` sub-class instances into a Map, due to JVM's type erasure, the relevant type parameter is gone.

```
val map = Map(0 -> new IntBox, 1 -> new StringBox)
val i: Any = map(0).exec() // compiles but not type safe and requires a cast later on
val ii: Int = map(0).exec() // compile error :(
// would work but in general it is not known at this point that type 'Int' is required
val iii: Int = map(0).exec().asInstanceOf[Int]
```

**So, the question is how to define a type-safe *get* operation.** Pls. note that the `Box` sub-classes are provided by the end-user of the code, hence, I have no control how many `Boxes` are present (so, individual matching using `TypeTags` are not possible).

So far, I tried to find a generic solution with `TypeTags`but didn't succeeded (by adding type tag fields to Box but as the type parameters are also removed I didn't gain anything). I'm happy to modify `exec` (or add an wrapper) so that at the end (an always successful) cast could be done -- but I'm unsure how get the right type information at that point. I'd also be happy to use libraries like Shapeless. (However, I'm doubtful if I could use Shapeless `hmap` as I'm not able provide all possible conversions as implicits upfront). I also found some examples where type information is stored in the keys but this didn't help in my case, because when I could get the keys from another data structure in a type-safe manner, I could also do this for the values in the first place. Any hints?

Comment: At some point after getting a value out of the map, you'll need to use it. Presumably in order to use it, you need to know or decide its type. Can you just downcast then?

Comment: You can get the class of an object, and then any property of that class, e.g. foo.getClass.getName - would that help? Another thought, why do you need explicitly set the type of unboxed variables - could you design an interface with methods working for any class present in that map?

Comment: @Yawar: I could do that (or better said, the end user of the library I try to create would need to do that) but then I pass Any's back to the end user and have the type unsafe situation as in Java with Objects. So, to me this is sth. I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Ashalynd: I assume this eventually leads to the same situation that I pointed out in my other comment: I'd need to pass back an 'Any' to the end user :(

Comment: @NepomukHirsch I think you can avoid returning `Any` to the user with a properly-designed getter method, e.g. `def tryGet[A: TypeTag](key: Int): Try[A]`. Now, the user can call it like so `map.tryGet[Int](0)`, `map.tryGet[String](1)`.

Comment: @Yawar Yes, technically his would be possible, however, then the user needs to fill in the ("missing") type...conceptually, from an end user perspective this not much different to manually casting the result (of course, getting a None instead of an exception in case of an incompatible type). So, probably I'll take shapeless's HList, which would lead to O(n) reads but that is ok in my case (but I don't need to provide all the implicits as in contrast to HMap)

Answer (score 0):

We discussed this, but just for completeness here is my answer:

```
import scala.util.Try

class AnyMap(map: Map[Int, Any] = Map.empty) {
  def add[A](int: Int, a: A): AnyMap =
    new AnyMap(map + (int -> (a: Any)))

  def tryGet[A](int: Int): Try[A] = Try(map(int).asInstanceOf[A])
}
```

This is just upcasting all values and shoving them into the same
`Map[Int, Any]`, and then downcasting them on retrieval.

Example usage:

```
val anyMap = new AnyMap
anyMap.add(0, 1).add(1, true).tryGet[Boolean](1)
```

Output:

```
Try[Boolean] = Success(true)
```

I believe this is fairly reasonable because we are already used to
passing in type parameters in Scala in a variety of places; having to
pass in a parameter in fact should serve as a useful reminder that we're
doing something out of the ordinary here. In fact thanks to type
inference sometimes we can specify the overall expression's return type
and avoid passing in an explicit type parameter to the method call:

```
val tryValue: Try[Boolean] = anyMap.add(0, 1).add(1, true).tryGet(1)
```

Output:

```
tryValue: Try[Boolean] = Success(true)
```